# Notation for sum of matrix with another matrix composed of copies of a vector

Tags: matrices, summation, vectors

I want to sum matrix $\mathbf{A}$ ($n \times d$) and a matrix composed of $n$ copies of vector $\mathbf{b}$ ($d \times 1$) as follows:

$\mathbf{A}+\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{b^T \\ \vdots \\ b^T}\end{bmatrix}_{n \times d}$

In MATLAB or Julia this would be equivalent to:

```
A .+ b'
```

Is there any succinct mathematical notation for this operation, or is the notation I used here the most appropriate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{1}= \pmatrix{1\\1\\ \vdots \\1}$

You want $\mathbf{A}+ \mathbf{1} \, \mathbf{b}^T$

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the $n \times 1$ vector with all entries equal to $1$, you could write

$$\mathbf{A}+\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{b^T \\ \vdots \\ b^T}\end{bmatrix}_{n \times d} = A + \mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{b} $$ using tensor product.